# Login form return POST data

Tags: php, debian, codeigniter-3

I moved my Codeigniter website code to a new server and the login screen is no longer working. The problem seems to be that the login screen is not returning POST data.  I have created a simple view and controller which works on the old site but returns nothing on the new site.  In this case 'works' means it displays the username and password entered.

I changed from Debian 7.11 to 8.6 which changed PHP 5.4.45 to 5.6.27.
Does anyone have any suggestions?  Your help would be much appreciated.

**VIEW xlogin**

```
<!-- Begin Login Form -->
  <form action="http://bdev.com/exverify/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="modal-body">
     <input id="username" name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
     <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
           <label>
              <p></p>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <div>
              <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
           </div>
        </div>
           <label><a href="login/forgetpassword" class="rLink" tabindex="5">Forgot your password ?</a></label>
  </div>
  </form>  <!-- End # Login Form -->
```

**CONTROLLER Exverify**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Exverify extends CI_Controller 
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
  }

  public function index()
  { 
    echo "<h1>Exverify experimental page</h1><br>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit(1);
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Returns nothing?  Have you checked the error log?  Lots of changes between PHP 5.4 and 5.6

Comment: There is nothing in the codeigniter error log.  Is there another log I should check?

Comment: Web server log or PHP log.  If there is a PHP fatal error or syntax error, it won't reach CI's log.

Comment: Simplify things: comment out your __construct() for now and test again. Also, make sure you are not getting a redirect in there somehow. For instance, if you POST to `http://bdev.com/exverify/` but there's an .htaccess redirect to `http://www.bdev.com/exverify/` the POST data will be lost.

Comment: I found the apache2 logs in /var/apache2/log and there is no error, there is an access entry for POST whih makes me think there isn't a redirect.

Comment: @Devon I found the apache2 logs in /var/apache2/log and there is no error,  there is an access entry for POST which makes me think there isn't a redirect.  The site is bdev.com on my local network.    bdev.com:80 192.168.1.215 - - [23/Dec/2016:13:27:07 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 872 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
bdev.com:80 192.168.1.215 - - [23/Dec/2016:13:27:19 -0500] "POST /exverify/ HTTP/1.1" 404 226 "http://bdev.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"

Comment: Do you have error_reporting disabled?

Comment: @TunaMaxx I commented out construct() in my controller and there was no change.  I still get array(0) { }  for my output.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Hmm. Instead of `var_dump($_POST)` try `var_dump($this->input->post(NULL, FALSE));` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @TunaMaxx I tried var_dump($this->input->post(NULL,FALSE)); and unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Devon after changing the sites-available conf file to add more error logging there is now an error message in /var/log/apaches/error.log of AH00128: File does not exist: <full path to CI controller> the problem probably is related to the change from apache2 2.2 to 2.4 that is part of the debian change.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problems by enabling mod-rewrite with 'a2enmod rewrite'.

So the problem was really an apache problem moving from 2.2 to 2.4 preventing codeigniter from working.  Thanks for the help, asking good questions.